# change cell background color

Tags: colors, background

http://jsfiddle.net/mannagod/Zq6w4/

```
    now = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
cells = document.getElementById('months').getElementsByTagName('td');
for (c = 0; c < cells.length; c++) {
    if (cells[c].firstChild.nodeValue == now) {
        cells[c].style.backgroundColor = 'red' //today's scripture reading
        cells[c].style.color = 'white'
    }
}
```

I would like to change the background and font colors for the cell that is the current month.  I tried the code above for the table below and I can't seem to make it work...

```
<table class="hovertable" id="hovertable" name="hovertable">

<tbody id="months">
    <tr>
        <td class="style2">
            <a href="01.htm">Jan</a></td>
        <td class="style2">
            <a href="02.htm">Feb</a></td>
        <td class="style2">
            <a href="03.htm">Mar</a></td>
        <td class="style2">
            <a href="04.htm">Apr</a></td>
        <td class="style2">
            <a href="05.htm">May</a></td>
        <td class="style2">
            <a href="06.htm">Jun</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style2">
            <a href="07.htm">Jul</a></td>
        <td class="style2">
            <a href="08.htm">Aug</a></td>
        <td class="style2">
            <a href="09.htm">Sep</a></td>
        <td class="style2">
            <a href="10.htm">Oct</a></td>
        <td class="style2">
            <a href="11.htm">Nov</a></td>
        <td class="style2">
            <a href="12.htm">Dec</a></td>
    </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify...what you want to do is have the current month be highlighted when the table first loads?

Comment: Correct - the current month's cell background colour should change so it stands out from the other months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This javascript should do what you want:

```
now = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
var d = new Date();
cells = document.getElementById('months').getElementsByTagName('td');
for (c = 0; c < cells.length; c++) {
    if (c == d.getMonth()) {
        cells[c].style.backgroundColor = 'red' //today's scripture reading
        cells[c].style.color = 'white'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I see what I was missing.